# type parameter with underlying type in - Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, scala-generics, type-members

Lets say I've a trait with a type `A` that is a subclass of `Any` and a method called `nextState` that has that same type as a parameter.

```
trait GameEnvironment {
  type A <: Any
  def nextState(state: A, input: Int): (A, Boolean)
}
```

This trait is then extended by a class called `Tetris` that overrides the type member `A` and the method `nextState`.

```
class Tetris extends GameEnvironment {
  override type A = ((Array[Array[Int]]), Int)

  def nextState(state: (Array[Array[Int]], Int), input: Int): 
  ((Array[Array[Int]], Int), Boolean) = {


     ((state, false))
  }
}
```

Now in another class called `ReinLib` I create a `GameEnvironment`, and I also have a function that takes in a parameter `GameEnvironment#A`.

```
class ReinLib(val mode: String) {
  val env : GameEnvironment = new Tetris()

  def simulateStep(state: GameEnvironment#A, input: Int): (Boolean) = 
    {
       env.nextState(state, input)._2
    }
}
```

Now if I compile this code I get an error

> type mismatch state.type (with underlying type...

From what I gather this happens since the compiler is not certain which type `state` has. However I could not seem to find how to solve my issue, so I'm wondering how one would get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `GameEnvironment#A` is way too vague, it is essentially completely unrelated to the type of state used in `env`.

You probably want something like this:

```
trait GameEnvironment {
  type A
  def nextState(state: A, input: Int): (A, Boolean)
}

class Tetris extends GameEnvironment {
  override type A = ((Array[Array[Int]]), Int)

  def nextState(state: A, input: Int): (A, Boolean) = {
    (state, false)
  }
}

class ReinLib(val mode: String) {
  val env: GameEnvironment = new Tetris()

  def simulateStep(state: env.A, input: Int): Boolean = {
    env.nextState(state, input)._2
  }
}
```

It compiles successfully, because now `env.nextState` can accept `state: env.A` as parameter.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced this will work... can you give an example of calling `simulateStep`? For instance: 
`new ReinLib("").simulateStep((Array(Array(1, 2, 3)), 0), 0)` does not compile. I am thinking you might need to either make `A` a generic type parameter instead of a type member, or maybe change env to be `val env: Tetris = new Tetris()`?

Comment: I tried something this before, but I could not make it work since env was var instead of val earlier on. Thanks for the help
edit: It did compile with the change for me at least Joe, so it seems to work at least.

Comment: @JoeK Once you hide the concrete type `Tetris` under the general type `env: GameEnvironment`, you lose the ability to pass any concrete arrays from the outside, because it could just as well be `env: GameEnvironment = if (math.random < 0.5) new Tetris() else new Quake()`. Therefore, the `state: env.A` must be provided by the `GameEnvironment` itself. As it is, the interface is incomplete and not very useful, because it is missing the "base case". It makes more sense as soon as you have `def initState: A` in `GameEnvironment`.

Comment: Okay, yeah that makes sense. My point was indeed specifically about passing state from the outside, but if that's not needed, and states are always internal to that class, that's fine.